# How do I convert a currency string like $1,248.99 to a decimal in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert any currency string to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753701/convert-any-currency-string-to-double)

How do I convert a currency string like `$1,248.99` to a decimal in C#?

Comment: Simlar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753701/convert-any-currency-string-to-double

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
var value = double.Parse(currency, NumberStyles.Currency);
```

Answer (score 2):

both Parse and TryParse have a numberstyle argument, so at its most simple

```
var data = "$1,248.99";
var outvalue = decimal.Parse(data,NumberStyles.Currency);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out `Convert.ToDecimal(s)` or `decimal.Parse(s)`

Answer (score 0):

Try Convert.ToDecimal(String, IFormatProvider)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k6z9cdw.aspx