# How to format a Currency string to Integer?

Tags: c#, formatting, integer, currency

I have a string with currency format like $35.00 and this has to be converted to 35.

Is that possible to retrieve using `String.Format{ }`

Comment: Something very similar was asked before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753701/convert-any-currency-string-to-double

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert any currency string to double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753701/convert-any-currency-string-to-double)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
int value = int.Parse("$35.00", NumberStyles.Currency);
```

Should give you the answer you need.

However, a value like $35.50 converted to an integer will likely not return what you want it to, as Integers do not support partial (decimal) numbers. You didn't specify what to expect in that situation.

**[EDIT: Changed double to decimal which is safer to use with currency]**

If you want to get a value of 35.5 in that situation, you might want to use the decimal type.

```
decimal value = decimal.Parse("$35.00", NumberStyles.Currency);
```

Note that you have to be **very** careful when dealing with money and floating point precision.

Comment: You should use the `decimal` type for all currency/money-related operations.

Comment: Ah yes, a very good point. I personally never write code that has to do with money and tend to forget the decimal type even exists.

Comment: If it worked for you, consider marking it as the answer. That way other people with the same problem know what worked. Glad you got it.