# How to compare currency or alphanumeric values in C#

Tags: c#

The value that extracted from the application is in string format for ex. "$0.38". So, I segregated each character in the given string using IsDigit then appended them together using string builder. The digit can also be alphanumeric like "12,365.23 AS". Is there a way to recover only numeric part (along with the decimal) from the given string.
But Output I receive is "38" instead of "0.38". I also want to compare that the given string value lies between the upperLimit and lowerLimit provided. 
Please let me know how to proceed with the same.

```
string Value = "$0.38";

int upperLimit = 2500;
int lowerLimit = 50000;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//sb.Append(someString);
foreach (char amin in Value)
{
    if (System.Char.IsDigit(amin))
    {
        sb.Append(amin);
    }
}
int compareVal = Convert.ToInt32(sb.ToString());

Console.WriteLine("value for comparision" + " " + compareVal);
```

Comment: `Int32` is simple the wrong Type for storing Currency. Use `double`.

Comment: You could instead strip the currency indicator from the string and convert it directly to a double

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format Currency string to integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094334/format-currency-string-to-integer)

Comment: This is because '.' is not a digit and it will give 038 which when you convert will produce 38 instead of 0.38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are omitting the decimal point and you are not using a decimal data type to hold the converted value. The real way to go is to convert the currency string to a decimal number:

```
CultureInfo usCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US)";
decimal amount = decimal.Parse(Value, NumberStyles.Currency, usCulture);
```

You can then perform a proper numeric comparison:

```
if (amount <= upperLimit && amount >= lowerLimit)
    ....
```

I first marked the question as a duplicate, but then changed my mind. I still think it is very much related to: [Convert any currency string to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753701/convert-any-currency-string-to-double)

Comment: I am getting "The name 'NumberStyles' does not exist in the current context" this error when I try to use this

Comment: @Ansh You need to add the `System.Globalization` namespace, of course...

Comment: let say if the string is in form of combination of alphabets and numerals, then how to proceed? I used string builder because of that.

Comment: let say if the string is in form of combination of alphabets and numerals, then how to proceed? I used string builder because of that. Lets say it is "abcd1,002.38". Can you help me through in this case?

Comment: Well, if the format of the string does not follow a given currency format, things get a bit harder. In that case it depends a bit on the number format, but I guess I'd limit the number of characters possible, for example to numbers, +, -, comma and period and use your string builder approach and the number conversion afterwords, or I'd look for a regular expression that extracts decimal numbers from strings and use that before the number conversion and comparison.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons why you will get `38`:

1. `StringBuilder` looks like `"038"`, since `"."` is not a digit (just like `"$"`).
2. `Convert.ToInt32(...)` returns an integer which doesn't allow decimal digits.

The better data type for currencies is `decimal`, a high precision floating point data type so to say.

Try

```
var amount = decimal.Parse(Value , NumberStyles.Currency)
var isInLimit = upperLimit <= amount && amount <= lowerLimit; // i guess you swapped upper and lower limit btw. ;)
```

instead.

### Edit

In order to use the [`NumberStyles`-Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx), you will have to use tha correct namespace in your file:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Comment: would this not cause problems if you had a number in the 0,000.00 format? (only asking because OP said its a string value)

Comment: No. This case is handled by the current culture. If your current culture's number style is different, you need to pass the proper culture info.

Comment: "The name 'NumberStyles' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

The best way is using one of the overloads of `decimal.Parse`:

```
string Value = "$0.38";
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

decimal dd=decimal.Parse(Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol|System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,culture);
```

Note the use of [NumberStyles enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx).That way you can control exaclty the parsing.

Comment: Please don't parse currencies as `double`, use `decimal` in order to support penny-values like `0.1`.