# String to decimal parsing C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse or convert a string to decimal in C#.

I need to be able to parse strings like,

$123,345,676.8999 to its equivalent 123345676.90.

I need to have only 2 places after the decimal point and that needs to be suitably rounded.

Can you guys please suggest a way to do the above? Basically, any string in the form of currency (with $,pound symbol etc). I should be able to parse it and convert it to decimal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753701/convert-any-currency-string-to-double

Comment: With _any_ currency, you need to be careful about rounding.  In some currencies `x.8999` would not be rounded at all.

Comment: Thanks Austin...ill kep that in mind...for now, US is my main concern.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
var val = double.Parse("$123,345,676.8999", NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol);
val = Math.Round(val, 2);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx) to perform the parsing -- the link has some samples on how the parsing works.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple answer: use [Decimal.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91fwbcsb.aspx)