# How can I trim currency symbol from string in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and I am using windows forms.
I want to subtract a value from `label1.Text` but I have problem with `£` symbol

Let's say `label1.Text` has value with `£` symbol like this: `label1.Text = £10.5`

Now I want to subtract a value from `label1.Text` but the issue that the £ is there. Let's say I want to subtract value of 5 from `label1.Text` as following:

```
double V = 5;
// now trim the £ sign from label1.Text
string s= Convert.ToString(label1.Text).Replace("£","");
// now s = 10.5 
double result = Convert.ToDouble(s); // it throws error here on this line
double Sum = result -v;
```

when I run the program it throws an error "Input string was not in correct format"

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong? Please help me how can I subtract a value from a string which contains £ symbol in correct way. Thank you

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: I've marked it as duplicate. The other Q&A is about `decimal` type, but you should be able to get the same result with doubles...

Comment: @ ekad. please see the update. tnx

Comment: @Kate...This works fine for me. Probably your `label1.Text` is empty or it has not the `£10.5` value!

Comment: @ Matías Fidemraizer . I do not understand why do not you allow other people to give more ideas/answers on here!!!!

Comment: Your code works fine as you can see [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NBlxe4), are you sure `label1.Text` actually has `£10.5` as its value?

Comment: @  S.Akbari . tnx for trying, no it is not empty I used messagebox.show() and it says 10.5  any idea? tnx

Comment: @Kate - click the link at the very top of your question. The answer at that link will fix this for you. (link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946025/string-to-decimal-parsing-c-sharp)