# How to convert formatted strings back to their original values?

Tags: .net

I just want to know how to total formatted strings like $ 100,000.00
Ive use a split method but it doesnt work when to many "," are there..

Comment: Let me understand: you have a string like that and you need to get the int amount?

Comment: If it's "solved", you should click the hollow checkmark next to the answer that was most helpful to you in solving the problem, not add `[solved]` to the title.

Comment: Sorry Im just new here... I am used to forums  :laughs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `NumberStyles` enumeration overload of the parse method in your example. e.g.

```
string money1 = "$100,000.00";
string money2 = "$300,500.00";
Double unformattedMoney = Double.Parse(money1, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
Double unformattedMoney2 = Double.Parse(money2, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);

Console.WriteLine(unformattedMoney + unformattedMoney2);
```

As a side note, this doesn't account for incorrect numbers and will throw an error if you attempt to format a bad string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a hold of them before they have been formatted. Trying to perform computations on numbers *after* they have been formatted is retarded, and highly error prone. Especially if your app is ever used under a different locale, where the thousands separator and the decimal point characters are not what you expected them to be.

Furthermore, be advised that the `String.Split` method will work just fine regardless of how many "," are there, so your problem is not the split method, it is something else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal moneyvalue = 1921.39m;
string html = String.Format("Order Total: {0:C}", moneyvalue);
Console.WriteLine(html);
```

Outputs the following:

Order Total: **$1,921.39**

or perhaps

```
String.Format("{0:#,###}", bigNumber);
```

Comment: I think he wants to revert the process to get back the original number

Answer (score 0):

if u are talking about currency specifically, check this [Convert any currency string to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753701/convert-any-currency-string-to-double)

the idea is to use `NumberStyle` class.
Hope this helps