# How to converting back from number format?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my app i use the following

```
newTotal.ToString("c", (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone())
```

to convert a inputted number to the number format of the phone. But is there a easy way to convert it back to a simple number again?

Comment: See this SO post
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753701/convert-any-currency-string-to-double][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753701/convert-any-currency-string-to-double

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use double.parse, like this:

```
var text = (1234,567).ToString("c");

var number = double.Parse(text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, cultureInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f56zcx39.aspx) family of methods. You don't specify what type newTotal is, but parse is available for all numeric primitive types.