# Can't get Currency formatted textbox into a decimal Model (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-binding

Inside my application I have a text box that has javascript convert values into a currency format. This is mandatory and nonnegotiable.

ie. 5.50 becomes $5.50 and -5.50 becomes ($5.50)

When I try to save I get a validation error because $5.50 is not valid for the ViewModel

```
//View file
 @Html.CustomEditorFor(m => m.CurrentTotal, "currency")

//Controller file. First thing in the controller method called
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
//... not getting to this
}

//ViewModel file
[Display(Name = "Current Total:")]
public decimal CurrentTotal
{
  get
  {
    return PropertyDictionary.GetDecimal("CurrentTotal", 0).Value;
  }
  set
  {
    PropertyDictionary.SetDecimal("CurrentTotal", value);
  }
}
```

I was wondering how I remove non-numeric excluding "." from the text box before it goes to the model and causes the ModelState to be invalid.

Once again I have inherited this application and am learning so I appreciate the time and patience!

Comment: Your formatted number is no longer a number it is a string...You should consider handling this two distinct data points-at least at the client.  Leave the decimal alone as a hidden, do your javascript conversion to a different visible control AND THEN use javascript to convert back to decimal (result goes in hidden control) and then postback.  Make sense?

Comment: Kind of. I was considering the JavaScript route to convert it before post back, this would not interfere with the user and I believe would be acceptable but I was wondering how this is normally done with MVC. I feel like this would be something common especially since you can do something along the lines of 
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
in the ViewModel File to cause all kinds of fits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know how to do this in MVC (though it looks like I should use custom model binders) I made a work around for this problem.

```
 $(document).submit(function () {
        $("input[type=text].currency").each
        (
            function () {
                $(this).val($(this).val().toString().replace('(', '-').replace("$", '').replace(")", ''));
            }
        );
    });
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

How about a call such as

```
double.Parse(currencyValue, NumberStyles.Currency);
```

as suggested in this [related link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753701/convert-any-currency-string-to-double). Check out [NumberStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be.aspx) for additional options.

Comment: Parse will not work because it is bound to the model before it gets a chance to convert. I was doing this before hand in the ViewModel File and it would not work.