# Add All the Values from a Column DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, sum

I'm using WinForms. How do you add the values of the Price column if it has a '$' sign? I am able to add the values when the column doesn't contain the "$" sign, but when it does the system throws an error.

This is what i have so far. This adds all the values from the price column and sums it up if it doesn't contain a '$' sign.

```
private void sum_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Total_TxtBx.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows
                        where row.Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty
                        select Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[2].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();
}
```

($1.00 + $2.00 + $3.00)
Total TextBox should Equal = $6.00

[image]

Comment: Why not add this after the 1st where : `where !row.Cells[3]. FormattedValue. ToString(). Contains("$")`  ?

Comment: Those `$` signs should not be part of data. The data of the column should be a number data type, but the `Format` should contain `$` sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one can see from this question [Convert any currency string to double](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2753701/6400526) you need to parse your value with a different overload:

```
string x = "$3.00";
var result = decimal.Parse(x, NumberStyles.Currency);

// result = 3.00
```

In your code:

```
private void sum_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Total_TxtBx.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows
                        where row.Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty
                        select decimal.Parse(row.Cells[2].FormattedValue, NumberStyles.Currency))
                       .Sum().ToString();
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something else. I'm trying to sum up the price row. But because each column has a $ sign the system throws an error.

Comment: I cant use this because, the system does not let me use `NumberStyles.Currency`. I tried `using System.Globalization`, but then  `row.Cells[2].FormattedValue` throws an error.

Comment: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: i had to add this line in `Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].FormattedValue)`, Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @taji01 Wait :) haha instead of adding that then you can do `FormattedValue.ToString()` or maybe even better - use `.Value` instead of `FormattedValue` (maybe then you even don't need to use the other overload of `parse`)